# Prevent the System from Entering Sleep or Turning off the Display while Application is Running

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm using Delphi XE Rio in Windows 8.1
My goal is to prevent system going into sleep mode and turning off the monitor.

I tried this one but not getting works.

> http://delphidabbler.com/tips/127

I'm using this

```
SystemCritical.IsCritical = true;
try
  // do critical operation here
  // without going in to sleep or turning off the display
finally
  SystemCritical.IsCritical = false;
end;
```

My computer just still turning off monitor then going to sleep.

Comment: Looking at the docs, perhaps ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED is needed?

Comment: Do you mean ```ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = $00000002;``` in ```const``` section?

Comment: I should have been clearer; I mean in the call to SetThreadExecutionState, i.e. perhaps it should be like this: SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED or ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED or ES_CONTINUOUS)

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much. Now I know DISPLAY is required to stop monitor being turned off. Then there's ES_USER_PRESENT Informs the system that a user is present. If a user is
present, the system will use the power policy settings set by the user.
Otherwise, the system does not wake the display device and will return
to the sleeping state as soon as possible.